# How do I apply this PDE as an image filter?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, convolution, image-processing

I'm trying to preprocess a height map image with a helmholtz-type equation as described in this [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Manuel_Gamito/publication/222551401_An_accurate_model_of_wave_refraction_over_shallow_water/links/00b4951a8b09d51acf000000.pdf).

The equation is:
$$ddx(h') + ddy(h') + y(h'-h) = 0$$

I solved for h and got:
$$\dfrac{ddx(h')}{y} + \dfrac{ddy(h')}{y} + h' = h$$

I then turned this into an equation of the form $Ax=b$ where $b$ is the source image and A is a matrix with elements around the diagonal corresponding to the central finite difference approximation of the second derivative of $h'$ divided by $y$ plus an extra $1$ added on the diagonal. I then attempted to solve this sparse system with a ConjugateGradient solver.

Unfortunately, the results don't look anything like a smoothed version of the original image. For very high y, the resulting image is mostly similar to h, but for lower y it quickly degrades into noise and eventually just a black image.

I suspect part of the issue is the way I'm dealing with the boundary conditions?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/krisr/034b5558fe4817f53d82) is my source code using Eigen and C++. If anyone can guide me in the correct description I would be very grateful!

Comment: I think there is chance I'm not setting up the matrix correctly with Eigen. I believe solving Ax=b here is basically the same as reversing the application of an edge detection kernel with an extra unit weight on the diagonal. If I setup A without the added unit weight and apply it directly to b (so no solving for x), the result should be the same as applying an edge detection kernel but it's much noisier than it should be.

Comment: This is definitely an applied math question and so I think it's on-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll see if there is a more appropriate place to post the question.

Comment: littleO, do you have a recommendation of a better place to post this question? I couldn't find an applied math stackexchange but I do want to ensure this question ends up in the appropriate place. Specifically, I'm interested in learning how to solve PDEs by discretizing them with boundary conditions. I think it's the last part that I may not have captured correctly, but I don't even know if the way I turned this into a linear system makes sense. I don't really need to solve this particular problem - it just seems like an interesting way to learn more about solving and applying PDEs.

Comment: No you misunderstood my comment -- I think your question is definitely on topic here. This is a good place to ask your question. I made that comment because someone else voted to close.

Comment: Oops! littleO, thank you for the support :).

Comment: @Kris I don't know anything about your problem personally, but Peter Kovasi has an anisotropic diffusion function on his page; perhaps his implementation may be of help to you? http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns